# SQL Aggregate value in column datewise

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Below is my database values.

[image: db_values]

I am looking for sum of values in column header datewise and I have MS Access database. Can anyone help me to build SQL query?
Please find below expected output.

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the set of dates, then you can use conditional aggregation.  In MS Access this uses the `iif()` function.  Your dates look like strings, so:

```
select a, b, c, d,
       sum(iif(store_date = '17-09-2016', val, 0)) as [17-09-2016],
       sum(iif(store_date = '18-09-2016', val, 0)) as [18-09-2016],
       sum(iif(store_date = '19-09-2016', val, 0)) as [19-09-2016],
       sum(iif(store_date = '20-09-2016', val, 0)) as [20-09-2016]
From t
Group by a, b, c, d;
```

You should store dates in the database using the built-in date data type.  However, if you must store them as strings, I would strongly encourage you to use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.  This is useful because you can use it for ordering and for range comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

In case dates are potentially in the hundreds that a conditional aggregate pivot is not feasible, consider a [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8), a unique SQL operation available in the Jet/ACE SQL dialect (not in other RDMS).

```
TRANSFORM SUM(t.val) AS SumOfVal
SELECT t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D
PIVOT t.Store_date;
```

Do note: there is a limit of 255 columns in any Access table/query. Hence, if your table results in 250+ unique dates, you will have to split up into multiple crosstabs. You can filter dates accordingly with the `PIVOT ... IN` clause:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(t.val) AS SumOfVal
SELECT t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D
PIVOT t.Store_date IN ('17-09-2016', '18-09-2016', '20-09-2016');
```